# Probability 5-card hand contains exactly 2 pairs

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that a five-card poker hand contains two pairs (that is, two of each of two different kinds and a fifth card of a third kind)?

The textbook answer is 198/4165

But why doesn't it work that:

Since we know the first card can be any card, it will be 52/52, the next card must be one of the same kind which is just 3/51, since there's 4 cards of a kind and one has already been picked.

Then repeat for the next card excluding the remaining 2 cards of the last kind, 48/50, and the next being one of the same here 3/49.

The last card being any other card 44/48

Multiply them all together (52 * 3 * 48 * 3 * 44) / (52 * 51 * 50 * 49 * 48) * 5!, the possible permutations  = 1584/4165, why does this process not work when the logic seems reasonable?

Comment: The second card doesn't have to be the same as the first card, does it? So your whole calculation breaks down.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to pay attention to whether you're counting permutations - sequences of items where the order matters - or combinations - sets of items where the order doesn't matter.

Consider an example two-pair hand, A♡ A♢ 2♡ 2♢ 3♡.

Your formula $52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 3 \cdot 44$ counts this exact *permutation* once. But if the order of the cards matters, it misses out on permutations that make two pairs but aren't in the "AABBC" pattern, like 3♡ A♡ A♢ 2♡ 2♢ and A♡ 2♡ A♢ 2♢ 3♡.

The formula $52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 3 \cdot 44$ counts this one *combination* of cards eight times:

- A♡ A♢ 2♡ 2♢ 3♡
- A♡ A♢ 2♢ 2♡ 3♡
- A♢ A♡ 2♡ 2♢ 3♡
- A♢ A♡ 2♢ 2♡ 3♡
- 2♡ 2♢ A♡ A♢ 3♡
- 2♡ 2♢ A♢ A♡ 3♡
- 2♢ 2♡ A♡ A♢ 3♡
- 2♢ 2♡ A♢ A♡ 3♡

So this product is not all of the valid permutations, and is more than the number of valid combinations.

If you have the number of valid permutations, you can divide by the total number of permutations $\frac{52!}{5!} = 52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48$. Or if you have the number of valid combinations, you can divide by the total number of combinations ${52 \choose 5} = \frac{52!}{(5!)(47!)} = \frac{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48}{5!}$. Whenever order doesn't matter, the number of valid permutations of size $k$ is of course $k!$ times the number of valid combinations of size $k$, which matches the ratio of these totals.

The simplest way to correct this approach is to note that $52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 3 \cdot 44$ counts every valid combination exactly $8$ times, so the true number of valid combinations is $\frac{52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 3 \cdot 44}{8}$. Then the final probability is
$$\frac{52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 3 \cdot 44 \cdot (5!)}{8 \cdot 52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48}$$

(It's also correct to find the number of valid permutations as $52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 3 \cdot 44 \cdot 15$ where $15$ is the number of ways to reorder the string "AABBC". But finding that count $15$ is a bit of a task, and the logic connecting this into the total is less obvious.)

Answer (score 3):

$\frac {1584}{4165} = \left(\frac {198}{4165}\right)(8)$

So, where did that factor of 8 disappear to?

We can interchange the cards in a pair, and we have two pairs in which we can make this swap.  And we can swap the two pairs themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You have $C^{13}_2$ ways of choosing $2$ pairs. Each pair can be colored $C^4_2$ ways. The last card can be chosen among $44$. So in total, you have $44C^{13}_2(C^4_2)^2$ possible hands, out of $C^{52}_5$.